# Contro-M z/OS: Save "Why screen" for each job waiting execution in Control-M

Tags: mainframe, jcl, control-m

In Control-M, is there a way to get the job names(s) waiting to execute and the reasons for waiting (Time, conditions, resources)? This info is in the "Why screen".

I've only managed to get the AJF job status but I'd like to go further.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a question mark beside the job will show the list of conditions it is waiting on. If you want to bypass any of the conditions, put an "A" beside the condition you want to bypass and confirm.

Comment: Yes, I know that part, and I think I finally found what I need, that is the KSL REPJOBMO. It gives me a dataset with all the jobs in 'wait schedule' status and the reason why.

Comment: Still, Thank you!

Comment: @csbl If you did find the answer, you should post it! answering your own question is encouraged. That way, if other people come to the site looking for the same information they can see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Quote from your own comment below the previous answer (slightly edited):

> ... use the KSL REPJOBMO. It gives a dataset with all the jobs in 'wait schedule' status and the reason why.